# Salesforce Data Migration API Limit

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, salesforce1-app

I vaguely remember we can file a case to salesforce to relax daily API limit during data migration window? is this true?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Salesforce will temporarily raise the limit after asking some basic questions such as:

- Specific details on how you will benefit from the increase
- What is the source system?
- How many source systems?
- What limits does the source system have?
- What limit do you need?
- How long do you need the increased limit?

Support can grant an increase up to 50,000 without escalation; higher limit requests are possible, but need justification.